# Decorate all controller methods laravel

Tags: php, laravel, decorator

In Python I can decorate a method using @decorator's sugar syntax on the function, but in php I can't do that.

I would like to decorate some methods in my controllers so I don't have to add Try Catch on each one.

My decorator would execute the normal method and if there is an exception it would return a defined structure.

No see si me expliqué In Python I can decorate a method using @decorator's sugar syntax on the function, but in php I can't do that.

I would like to decorate some methods in my controllers so I don't have to add Try Catch on each one.

My decorator would execute the normal method and if there is an exception it would return a defined structure.

I don't know if I understand what I want to do.

Comment: This may be help full for you: https://dev.to/ahmedash95/design-patterns-in-php-decorator-with-laravel-5hk6

Comment: You would be better looking to modify the standard error handler.  Your controllers extend the base controller and I don't think there is a way to wrap the public controller functions with something from the parent

Comment: I think that it help but i'm not sure how implement it xD anyway, Thanks I'll give it try

Answer (score 1):

If you really had to you could override the `callAction` method on your Controller, this is how that method looks by default:

```
public function callAction($method, $parameters)
{
    return $this->{$method}(...array_values($parameters));
}
```

This method gets called by the `ControllerDispatcher` when it needs to dispatch the Request to your Controller action. You can modify this to do your 'decorating' if you would like.

As mentioned in the comments, you could have the main `ExceptionHandler` handle the exceptions as well. Just depends at what point you need to act upon the Exception.